# What is the meaning of "we must have missed you"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I was missed from agenda list of minutes of meeting, hence I requested for including my name in the list.

But the chairperson of the meeting replied saying "we must have missed you".

I am confused? Is he saying, he missed me deliberately?

Answer (score 2):

Here "must" is used to indicate a likely circumstance, but one that the person can't know with complete certainty.

"We missed you" here means "we overlooked you".

A more elaborate sentence with the same meaning would be:

> The most likely explanation for this discrepancy is that we simply overlooked you when listing the attendees.

Note that in British English, this might be phrased "[missed you off](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/miss_off)".